# Error messages not thrown with fp_eval

Tags: expl3, expansion, fp

I'm writing some error-checking on values passed to a function, to raise an error if values are not OK, before passing them to `\fp_eval`. From what I've noticed, the call to `\fp_eval` messes with the error messages and I can't get them to be displayed.

Here is a MWE with what I'm trying to achieve. *It's a sanitized version of a much more complicated code, but I narrowed it down, apologies if it makes little sense as is.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { module } { invalid-option }{ Value~'#2'~invalid~for~"#1"~#3.}

\cs_new:Npn \__module_Function:n #1
{
    \str_case_e:nnF {#1}
    {
        { N } { 0.2 }
        { A } { 0.3 }
    }
    { \msg_error:nnxxx { module } { invalid-option } { Function } {#1} {\msg_line_context:} }
}

\cs_new:Npn \__module_OtherFunction:n #1
{
    \fp_eval:n {2 * (\__module_Function:n {#1})}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \test { m }{%
    \__module_Function:n {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \otherTest { m }{%
    \__module_OtherFunction:n {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \test{A}
    \test{N}
%   \test{X} %PRINT --> Package module Error: Value 'X' invalid for "Function" on line 37.
    
    \otherTest{A}
    \otherTest{N}
    \otherTest{X} % Cannot print this error
\end{document}
```

The call to `\test` with a bad value throws a correct error, but the call to `\otherTest` gives me this error:

```
! You can't use `\edef' after \the.
<argument> \cs_set_nopar:Npx
```

How can I circumvent this to have my error correctly raised ?

Comment: Messages are not expandable: that's the reason we don't use standard error messages inside `\fp_eval:n`.

Comment: Your illustration of error message (You can't use \edef followed by \cs_set_nopar:Npx) is very good. Thanks! It shows the basic problem of the expl3 language. It brings totally new terminology, concept of thinking and replaces all TeX internal commands. But in the final consequence TeX is the program which interprets this and it uses its own terminology and error messages. The programmer which are thinking only in the categories and terminologies of expl3 must be totally lost. To implement a new layer over TeX is bad idea. I always say that.

Comment: And how can I check the value before passing it to `fp_eval` then ?

Comment: you could check how fp_eval sets its own exceptions and error messages. Or use `\msg_expandable_error:nnfff`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140460/discussion-on-question-by-3isenheim-error-messages-not-thrown-with-fp-eval).

Comment: I've moved the comments not directly concerning the question to chat

Comment: I wonder if we could have some more context here: can you explain why you need to deal with non-valid input for a floating-point calculation?

Comment: @JosephWright To be fair that sounds like something that is useful *by itself*? If you suspect it's some sort of XY problems it's possible to say e.g. "this problem is really hard. Is there any alternatives?" although I don't think it is that hard anyway.

Comment: @user202729 I'm thinking more that (La)TeX isn't really suitable for complex calculations. As such, the typical use cases for `\fp_eval:n` involve input that is predictably valid, even if the results might be non-trivial (s.g. sines for angles of image rotation). So I wonder what the wider context is here: I'm not sure there's a reasonable use case involving non-valid expressions.

Comment: I'm writing a CVSS score computation package. Depending on an input string, you compute a score (from n0.0 to 10.0). https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.1